# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.squareup/otto/pom.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting below mentioned error when I'm trying to run my application.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForAmazonCheezCoverage'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.squareup/otto/pom.xml
>       File1: /Users/afourtest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.crashlytics.android/crashlytics/1.1.13/e821eafa1bf489a26bdb71f95078c26785b37a1/crashlytics-1.1.13.jar
>       File2: /Users/afourtest/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup/otto/1.3.7/69d90fd7fb70e54746e26c10454c220e40a775ce/otto-1.3.7.jar

My app build.gradle is [here](http://pastebin.com/vTv5ZKJA)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add to build.gradle:

```
android {
...
    packagingOptions {
         exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup/otto/pom.xml'
}
```

Also, instead of **exclude** you could use **pickFirst**

Comment: I have same issue, when I exclude 
`exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/pom.properties'`
`exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/pom.xml'` those two files I still get error