# Gradle build error, Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug' in pom.xml

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Hello people i get the following error when iam trying to run my android app:

> Gradle build error, Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug' 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META/INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.xml

[image]

These are my both gradle files:

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
  all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
 }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the other one:

> 

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.dp.liveupdatestatus"
     minSdkVersion 18
     targetSdkVersion 26
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
         'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
// This is needed for firebase UI
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help!

Comment: add this `packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34673607/3395198 . Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks bro. you can put this as answer if you want and than i can accept it as the right solution if you want. Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

```
android {  
......
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
}
```

add this to exclude the META inf files

Comment: thank you but this did not solve the problem.